# React Router Query Parameters

Tags: javascript, url, reactjs, query-string, react-router

I have a React application which is using `react-router` v2.4. I have a route defined like so:

```
<Router history={this.props.history}>
    <Route path="/:organisationId/objects"
           component={ObjectsPage}
           onEnter={(state) => {
               this.props.dispatch(objectsFetch(
                   state.params.organisationId,
                   state.location.query
               ));
           }}
    />
</Router>
```

Essentially, this route dispatches an action to fetch some objects from an API which are then rendered in a tabular format. I would like this table to be searchable, sortable and paginated and I think it would be appropriate to store the state of the table in the URL as query parameters so it can be refreshed and browser back/forward functionality isn't broken.

In order to update my table component I make a call to `browserHistory` with a URI similar to this (note the query parameters):

```
browserHistory.push('/0f08ac61-ddbd-4c73-a044-e71b8dd11edc/objects?page=2&search=query&sort=firstname|desc');
```

However, this doesn't trigger `react-router` into thinking the route has updated as the `onEnter` callback is never fired even though the browser history is updated with the new query string. I think I understand why this is happening; since the query string isn't part of the defined route I guess the package won't pick the change up.

Is there a way to use `react-router` with query parameters like this or will I have to make my filters part of the URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `onChange` in the route definition - `onEnter` is called the first time you hit a route and `onChange` is called when the route status changes:

```
<Route path="/:organisationId/patients"
       component={PatientsPage}
       onEnter={(state) => {
           this.props.dispatch(patientsFetch(
               state.params.organisationId,
               state.location.query
           ));
       }}
       onChange={(state) => {
           this.props.dispatch(patientsFetch(
               state.params.organisationId,
               state.location.query
           ));
       }}
/>
```

Comment: Is seems like onChange only gets called if query params are changed, and not if route params are changed. Is that correct, and if so, why?